# eclipse321 crashes a lot

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-3.2

while I'm working with eclipse 3.2.1 it's crashes and the message is like:

```
JVM terminated exit code = 1
C:\program Files(x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_30\BIN\javaw.exe
-Xms40m 
-Xmx256m
-jar C:\*****\eclipse321\startup.jar
-os win32
-ws win32
-arch x86
-launcher C:\*****\Eclipse321\eclipse.exe
-name Eclipse
-showsplash 600
-exitdata 1548_c0
-vm C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_30\BIN\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Xms40m
-Xmx256m
-jar C:\*****\Eclipse321\startup.jar
```

what could it be?

I'm using win7 in 64 bit.

tnx

Comment: Have you tried using a newer version of eclipse?

Comment: I can't. it's my worksplace policy to work with this version

Comment: A maximum memory of 256 megabytes seems small. My Eclipse (Kepler) consumes 429 megabytes.

Comment: sry... will delete my comment

Comment: Eclipse 3.2 is almost eight years old and has not been supported for very long. You will probably not find anyone interested in putting in the time to investigate this. You will need to either convince your employer to use a more modern Eclipse or put down the time yourself. Sorry.

Comment: If you want to increase the possibilities a little that someone will look at this, you need to give us a little more details. Have this worked before? If so, what is different now? Does it work with another JVM?

Comment: It's working on the rest of the computers of the team.
I'm new in this team so I can't tell what's wrong in this computer.
It happend to me before so I formatted the computer but it was not usefull as I see.

Comment: [PEBCAK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_error)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse 3.2.1 is not (and never) was supported on Windows 7. Eclipse 3.2.1 came out long before Windows 7. While I can appreciate that your workplace policy dictates that you *must* use this version of Eclipse (likely to backport a maintenance issue) they should not be dictating that you *must* use this version with an incompatible OS. If you really must use this version (which, as others have mentioned, is almost 8 years old) you should be running it on a compatible OS.

The list of target Operating Systems for 3.2.1 are available here:
http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/development/readme_eclipse_3.2.1.html